# PowerShell Compress-Archive By File Extension

Tags: powershell, zip, powershell-5.0

How can I use the PowerShell 5.0 `Compress-Archive` cmdlet to recursively take any .config files in a directory and zip them up while maintaining the directory structure. Example:

```
Directory1
    Config1.config
Directory2
    Config2.config
```

The aim is a single zip file also containing the above directory structure and only config files.

Comment: What do you mean? find a config-file, zip it (only the config-file) and leave the zip-file in the same location as the config-file?

Comment: I added an illustration.

Comment: The file-structure was the only clear part tbh. What does the desired output look like? You want one zip file containing all the config files? Or one zip file per config file?

Comment: A single zip with the above directory structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest copying the files to a temporary directory and compress that. Ex:

```
$path = "test"
$filter = "*.config"

#To support both absolute and relative paths..
$pathitem = Get-Item -Path $path

#If sourcepath exists
if($pathitem) {
    #Get name for tempfolder
    $tempdir = Join-Path $env:temp "CompressArchiveTemp"

    #Create temp-folder
    New-Item -Path $tempdir -ItemType Directory -Force | Out-Null

    #Copy files
    Copy-Item -Path $pathitem.FullName -Destination $tempdir -Filter $filter -Recurse

    #Get items inside "rootfolder" to avoid that the rootfolde "test" is included.
    $sources = Get-ChildItem -Path (Join-Path $tempdir $pathitem.Name) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

    #Create zip from tempfolder
    Compress-Archive -Path $sources -DestinationPath config-files.zip

    #Remove temp-folder
    Remove-Item -Path $tempdir -Force -Recurse
}
```