# How to use Powershell Compress-Archive to compress only pdfs in a folder?

Tags: powershell, pdf, zip, compression, alteryx

I'm working on an Alteryx workflow which creates multiple pdfs and outputs them to a directory. I need to call a Powershell script at the end of the workflow to compress the pdfs into a zip file and save it in the same location.

I found this:
[PowerShell Compress-Archive By File Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36136204/powershell-compress-archive-by-file-extension), but it requires copying the files to another location and then compressing them. Is there a way I can just compress all pdfs in a certain folder location and output the zip file in the same location? Due to restrictions in Alteryx I might not be able to work with the output if it is in a different location.

My current Powershell script:

`Compress-Archive -LiteralPath 'D:\temp\test zipping flow\' -DestinationPath 'D:\temp\final.zip' -Force`

This works perfectly, but tries to zip files with other extensions as well but I only want `.pdf` files.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `-LiteralPath` use `-Path`, so you can add a wildcard character `*`

```
Compress-Archive -Path 'D:\temp\test zipping flow\*.pdf' -DestinationPath 'D:\temp\final.zip' -Force
```

---

As alternative for when you need to use `-LiteralPath` (perhaps because the path contains characters that would be interpreted using `-Path` like square brackets), you could do this instead:

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath 'D:\temp\test zipping flow' -Filter '*.pdf' -File | 
Compress-Archive -DestinationPath 'D:\temp\final.zip' -Force
```

Comment: I tried using *.pdf, but did not know I had to change the path argument as well. Changing -LiteralPath to -Path worked perfectly.  Thanks @Theo